# what is wrong with this program.? what is causing the infinite loop. C

Tags: c

The function supposed to read each line from a file and send each line to an another function. but am getting an error on the commented part of the code. why is that?

I am storing each character in a character array. It should be simple enough. I don't understand why it isn't working. Is it because its an array that its not storing it in it?

I think I added enough details about the program, but I get the red thing saying I need to add more. Hopefully this is enough.

```
void exercise3(void)
{
    FILE *  inputFile;
    char    line[64];        
    int number_of_conversions=1;
    int i = 0;        
    printf("BEGIN EXERCISE 3\n");

    // Open the file /public/lab10ex3.txt for reading. Store the handle in the
    // variable inputFile.
    // (WRITE THE CODE HERE)

    inputFile=fopen("/public/lab10ex3.txt","r");

    // Test to ensure the file was successfully opened. If opening the file
    // failed, display an error message, and exit the program with an exit
    // code of 1.
    // (WRITE THE CODE HERE)

    if (inputFile==NULL){            
        printf("bad stuff \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Read each line from the file into the character array 'line'. Pass
    // each line of text to the processDrawCommand function.
    // (WRITE THE CODE HERE)

    while (number_of_conversions!=0 && number_of_conversions!=EOF ){                                       
        number_of_conversions=fscanf(inputFile,"%c",&line[i]);    //Error Here

          if (line[i]=='\n'){
              i=0;                  
              processDrawCommand('\n');
          }              
          processDrawCommand(line);
        i++;                                                            
    }
```

Comment: You should be using `fgets` to read a line into the array.

Comment: You write "I'm getting an error on the commented part of the code". Which error do you get ? Be more explicit we cannot guess.

Comment: if `line[i] == '\n'` you never terminate your string. No clue what `processDrawCommand` does, but if it expects a terminated string its about to be sorely disappointed. Cubia already noted below you have zero range checking on the top-end magnitude of `line[]` at all.

Comment: You have `processDrawCommand('\n');` and `processDrawCommand(line);`. In the first case, you pass a `char` and in the second, you pass a `char*`. What??

Comment: I guess you should also change `while (number_of_conversions!=0 && number_of_conversions!=EOF )` to `do{...}while(line[i-1]!=EOF);`

Comment: that could fail. number of conversions checks if the text is finished or i couldnt read the file at all.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I can notice is that the value of `i` in `&line[i]` can surpass the allocated array size of 64 that you have declared above :     `char line[64];`

This would mean that if you are analyzing a line that has more than 64 characters, you will get an out-of-bounds error and your program will fail.